# Superscript symbol in the title of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS to make a report for my company, and using ReportBuilder2.0. We have a registered trademark in the title and need to add the Ⓡ symbol as a superscript. I've looked on this site and others online and so far I've found how to use the chr() and chrW() to get the regular symbol using the 174 code, but that does not set it to superscript. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Place a placeholder and set value ="®" (174 code) and choose markup type to html.. see screenshot below [image: Place Holder]

For superscript try <sup>®</sup>  use sup tag like we do in html [superscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup)

Comment: Hey sorry its taken so long to get back to this question. We got busy at work and had to put down the report for a bit. So I added the place holder and used the value "<sup>&#174;</sup>" and marked the HTML option, and it is still only showing as a regular ® no superscripting.